# Error in Facebook Share Dialog

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, android-fragments, share

I encountered an unlike error. I tried to do the Facebook Share Dialog however I encountered this error in the logcat.

```
 10-17 15:44:39.026: E/AndroidRuntime(2534): com.facebook.FacebookException: Unable to create Intent; this likely means the Facebook app is not installed.
```

I have no idea what this means. I tried to search for it but there is no similar instance. Here is my code.

**TabFour.java**

```
public class TabFour extends Fragment {
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_four, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
    action.setProperty("book", "https://example.com/book/Snow-Crash.html");

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(getActivity(), action, "books.reads", "book")
            .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
        }
    });
}



@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {


    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

}
```

Here is my logcat.:

http://shrib.com/nointentstuff

Comment: do you have facebook application on the device you test your app

Comment: i recently realized it that I don't have the facebook installed in my emulator. will that fix things?

Comment: yes that is what your logcat is saying and the doc also says the same. check my post

Comment: What if the user doesn't have Facebook installed?  I have this ShareDialog in my app, but some users don't have Facebook installed. This should crash the app however should it?  How do I put a check or work around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> com.facebook.FacebookException: Unable to create Intent; this likely
>   means the Facebook app is not installed

Quoting from step 2 @ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/

**The Facebook SDK uses Facebook's native app to provide support for authentication when it's present. On a real device, you can test this by simply installing this app for free from Google Play. However, it's not possible to access Google Play on an emulator. If you want to test the flow there, we include a copy in the SDK that you can install.**

The installable APK of the Facebook app is in the bin folder of the SDK, and named FBAndroid-3.5.apk or similar. To install it onto an Android emulator, you'll first need to start the emulator.

Secondly, locate the adb tool in the platform-tools directory of your main Android SDK. On OS X, you will have chosen this location when you unzipped the Android SDK. On Windows, the SDK is installed into your home directory, under AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

Assuming you've placed the Facebook SDK in your home directory, you use adb to install the APK to the running emulator in OS X like this:

```
./adb install ~/facebook-android-sdk-3.5/bin/FBAndroid-3.5.apk
```

And on Windows, like this:

adb install %HOMEPATH%\facebook-android-sdk-3.5\bin\FBAndroid-3.5.apk
Once complete, check the apps screen of the emulator to check that the app has been installed correctly. If you need to force the upgrade of this app from a previous version, add the -r flag, like this on OS X:

```
./adb install -r ~/facebook-android-sdk-3.5/bin/FBAndroid-3.5.apk
```

Comment: wait i'll try in on a device.

Comment: It runs, but something unusual happened. Facebook appeared for a split second then its gone, completely gone. It seems like the facebook activity didn't even start. Any ideas?

Comment: @MiguelRivera problem may be you authentication you might not have logged into facebook . follow the docs. it has a example of share login and few more https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/

Comment: hey one last question, I tried it on a landscape orientation, the app suddenly forced stop. any ideas?

Comment: @MiguelRivera post a new question with the relevant stack trace and check the stack trace caused by part might give you a clue of what caused the force close

Comment: Uhhh... Am I the only one that finds it ridiculous that this crashes if Facebook isn't installed?!  I don't build my apps with a dependency that all users have Facebook installed.  Is there a check I need to do to see if Facebook is installed?

Answer (score 17):

For those who actually want to build their app for users who may not have Facebook app installed, make sure to include this check around your ShareDialog builder ([more info here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/#tips)):

```
if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), 
                                         FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
            .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
            .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

}
```

Comment: then how to share a post on the devices on which fb app is not installed?

Answer (score 12):

If the user doesn't have the app installed (ridiculous dependency from FB...) you can fallback to sharing from the browser:

```
String linkString = "https://developers.facebook.com/android";
if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this).setLink(linkString).build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
} else {
    String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + linkString;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

// **Manifest File**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**build.gradle**
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
        android:value="@string/app_name" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1854328631556764"
        android:exported="true" />


 private CallbackManager callbackManager;  // Global variable Declare 
private ShareDialog     mFacebookShareDialog;   // Global variable Declare 

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

  callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        fbloginButton = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.facebook_button);

        mFacebookShareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

}
```

**When Success full Login to facebook then call shareOnFaceboo kMethod its working**

```
   private void shareOnFacebook(){

        ShareLinkContent shareContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("The Simpson!")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.codecube.in/airbucks-project"))
                .build();

        mFacebookShareDialog.show(shareContent, ShareDialog.Mode.FEED);

        mFacebookShareDialog.registerCallback( this.callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                Log.v("MyApp", "Share success!"); //Showed if I press the share or the cancel button
                String postID = result.getPostId();
                Log.v("MyApp", "Share success!" +result);
                Log.v("MyApp", "Share success!" +postID);
                Log.v("MyApp", "Share success!" +result.getPostId());
                Log.v("MyApp", "Share success!" +result.toString());
                Log.v("MyApp", "Share success!" +result);

                CommonMethod.showAlert("Sucesssfully post in Fb  Post id -> " +postID +" Result " +result  ,MainActivity.this);

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.v("MyApp", "Share canceled"); //Only showed when I press the close button
                CommonMethod.showAlert("Post onCancel " ,MainActivity.this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.v("MyApp","Share error: " + e.toString());
                CommonMethod.showAlert("Post onError "+e ,MainActivity.this);
            }

        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```